# At run-time, from a .Net application, how do I set the "description" field displayed in Task Manager?

Tags: c#, .net, process, taskmanager

I have a general executable that hosts a single plugin which is selected according to the command line arguments. In Task manager, there is a column entitled "Description", which is blank for my process. As there are several instances of my host process running, I can't tell which process is which in Task Manager. How do I update the value of the description field at run-time so that I can identify which plugin is loaded in which process?

Comment: Isn't it simply the value assigned to the AssemblyDescription attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs file of the project?

Comment: And if it is, I don't think this information is updateable at runtime. Changing assembly identification at runtime could be considered a security risk.

Comment: Ah, is it? If you know this and/or have some info with which to confirm, you should make it an answer, so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Sometime it's better to stop thinking as programmers. To solve your question perhaps is better to use Process Explorer as replacement for task manager [Microsoft Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)

Comment: View + Select Columns, tick "Command Line".  Or use Console.Title so it is distinguishable in the Applications tab.

Comment: @Steve sometimes process explorer isn't available on the target machine, or is a bit heavy when you need to pull up the process list super quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the Value of the Assembly *Title* (not the Description).

```
    [assembly: AssemblyTitle("My Title")]
```

But as far as I can tell it is read-only.